# Where non-root web app should write it's log under ubuntu?

Tags: web-server, logging

I have a python we application that is executed under `www-data` for security purpose (not under `root`). On of it's processes can generate application specific log file, and i want to place this file somewhere. As i notices, `/var/log` has `root` owner and `drwxr-xr-x` rights, so my non-`root` app can't write log here. What is a correct place for writing log in this case? Do i need to trash `www-data` home folder with logs (like `~/.myapp.log`) or it's some idiomatic solution available?

Comment: Send the data to syslog. Syslog can write to /var/log . If you need to and if you have access, configure `/etc/rsyslog.conf` to write to a special file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's what `/dev/log` is for. You can configure the syslog daemon to redirect the messages from your application to any file you like.

From python, this should be as easy as calling 
[`syslog.syslog`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/syslog.html).

Comment: Syslog is good, but some logs may contain binary dumps in case of errors, so it's not an all-good solution O_O.

Answer (score 2):

Your app probably shouldn't be running as `www-data`. Create a new system user for it — `--system` option if you're using `adduser` — and place its files under `/srv/yourapp`. Then you can create a log directory for it, like `/var/log/yourapp`, or keep logs in `/srv/yourapp/logs`.

That way, your webserver runs as `www-data`, your app runs as `yourapp`, and you can start both from root. For example, using nginx with option `user  www-data;` in its configuration, and running your app as an uWSGI (it's an application container server) app with the appropriate

```
uid = yourapp
gid = yourapp
```

in the .ini config for yourapp in `/etc/uwsgi/apps-enabled/`. uWSGI configuration mirrors the style of nginx configuarion. You create app profiles in `/etc/uwsgi/apps-available/` and symlink them to `/etc/uwsgi/apps-enabled/`. Everything else should be handled by your distribution.

As far as I can tell, this is the cannonical approach. At least for Ubuntu and python webapps. And it makes general administration simpler: start-up scripts should work as intended without any special custom edits, updates shouldn't break anything... the usual benefits.

As an even more specific example, I have a MoinMoin wiki running as an uWSGI app behind nginx on Ubuntu.

From nginx site:

```
location = /wiki { return 301 /wiki/; }
location /wiki/ {
    gzip off;
    include uwsgi_params;
    uwsgi_param SCRIPT_NAME /wiki;
    uwsgi_modifier1 30;
    uwsgi_pass unix:/run/uwsgi/app/moin/socket;
}
```

From uWSGI moin.ini:

```
[uwsgi]
uid = moin
gid = moin

plugins = python
wsgi-file = /usr/share/moin/server/moin.wsgi
master = true

chmod-socket = 666
processes = 1
```

with all other settings completely default (`usr/share/uwsgi/conf/default.ini` for me)

MoinMoin has its own separate user

```
# grep moin /etc/passwd
moin:x:109:111::/srv/moin:/bin/false
```

and, because it was installed from the repository just like everything else (nginx, uwsgi), the remaining configuration is in `/etc/moin/`.